# Is it possible to limit the history records retrieved in Apex, by their parent, using SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql, history-tracking

A little context: you need to track the amount of products in an account (inventory management). To do this, you have a custom object that acts as a junction table between an account and a product. This object has a `quantity` field that has field history enabled.

```
 Id
 Name
Product__c (lookup)
Account__c (lookup)
Quantity__c (history enabled)
```

Now if you need to generate a report to get the exact amount of items in a certain account on a certain date, how can you filter just the last modification per item (the newest `NewValue` on the history per item)?

My main issue here, I believe, is that I don't know how to use SOQL to get only the latest history entry up to a date. This can become an issue for a huge history, because if I want to get a history, say, from January, internally I'd have to query everything in the history just to know what I had in stock until 1/Jan. The remaining records would be used to calculate what happened in the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query compiles for me and I believe it does what you want:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT NewValue
        FROM Histories
        WHERE Field = 'Name'
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
FROM Account
```

Comment: do you know if there's a way to get the values for an entire month with a query like this? I mean, if I'd like to know the changes in a month. The problem of filtering by the month is that if a change occurs in, say, December, and the next change only occurs in February, then the query won't return the value that stayed the same during January.

Comment: You could add a `CreatedDate` filter to your `WHERE` clause like `WHERE Field = 'Name' AND CreatedDate = LAST_MONTH`.

Comment: I think I know what to do now. I can't filter by the last month because the modification could take several months to be made. I think its best to do two queries. One to get the value in the start date (like your example), and other to query the changes between the start date and the end date (with a `WHERE` specifying the two dates).

Comment: Using `LAST_MONTH` was just an easy example to throw in the comments. Sounds like you get the idea.